# Is dual norm greater than the norm?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

I've been thinking:
$$x^Ty \leq ||x||\cdot|y||_* \implies \frac{x^Ty}{||x||}\leq ||y||_*$$

Does that tell me something about $||y||$ ?

I did not find it anywhere so probably I am thinking something wrong:
$$x^Ty \leq |x^Ty| =| x \cdot y| \leq ||x|| \cdot ||y||$$

Can I somehow show $||y|| \leq ||y||_*$$ for an arbitrary norm?

Comment: If that were true for any $y$ then by iterating the inequality one more time you would get
$$\|y\|\le\|y\|_*\le\|y\|_{**} = \|y\| $$
i.e. $\|y\| = \|y\|_*$, which we know is not true for most norms.